# ssh command fails when run with ssh-dss as hostKeyAlgortihm

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I am running two commands one after other.

I run in the following sequence second command fails with error code 255

First Command:

```
ssh -ladmin -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -oUserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts.sshHostKey \
  -oHostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa 172.23.13.35 echo AN_INTERESTING_STRING'
```

Second Command:

```
ssh -ladmin -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -oUserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts.sshHostKey \
  -oHostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-dss 172.23.13.35 echo AN_INTERESTING_STRING'
```

Just HostKeyAlgorithms are changed in both commands from ssh-dsa to ssh-dss.

But, If I reverse  the sequence of running these commands ( with ssh-dss as HostKeyAlgorithm first, then with ssh-dsa ). It all works fine.

This is only happening with me once I upgraded my openssh-clients version to openssh-clients-6.6.1 .
It was not happening my earlier version, which was openssh-clients-5.5 .

Does anyone knows the reason for all this?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely valid behaviour. As you can see in manual pages, the default value for `HostKeyAlgorithms` is quite long list of acceptable algorithms. And if you provide file containing some unknown algorithms, it will fail.

There was probably some change of the code between you mentioned versions, that the previous was ignoring unknown keys, instead of the new one is failing.

If you put there both algorithms, it will work for you in both cases. What is your use case and why are you trying to push openssh into such corner case?

Comment: I am pretty unknown to how these algorithms works. Can you tell me more about why command fails when run using seq1 and passes if, I  reverse. I think both the algorithms are known( ssh-dsa and ssh-dss ).

Comment: Yes, they are know, but if you force it to use only one, it will not use the other (for writing, nor for reading). Removing the explicit option or using both `ssh -ladmin -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts.sshHostKey -oHostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-dss,ssh-rsa 172.23.13.35 echo AN_INTERESTING_STRING'` would make it working again.

Comment: Got it that running using both algos, it works well. Sorry, but still I can't understand why it passes when we ran in reverse order ? Secondly, Why even the seq1 was passing in the previous versions. What has changed ? was this a bug in the previous versions ??

Comment: The thing is, that each of the commands is writing host keys into same known hosts file with different syntax and doesn't know the syntax of the other command. The earlier version was probably ignoring whole line if it was using different algorithm, the new one is probably reading address and if the algorithm is unknown for it, it fails.